# Kurento, invalid url while connecting with remote camera

Tags: java, streaming, webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I need convert rstp stream to webrtc format and display it on web page.

I try use kurento based on tutorial *kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/tutorials/java/tutorial-player.html*. 
I was able to connect in kurento with test online stream: *rtsp://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen03.stream*, but I have problem with connecting to my remote camera. Address this camera is in following pattern: *rtsp://user@password@ip_address:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1* . In vlc program stream is available but in kurento I get 'Invalid uri' error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon between the user & password instead of @ as you have above. e.g. `rtsp://user:password@ip_address:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1`

Comment: Sorry for mistake in my ask. I use colon between this part of url. My problem is caused by '@' in password. I can not change password. Is opened issue for this in https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker/issues/173 , but nobody solved this problem.